# get first and second place of a game

Tags: python, class, compare

I'm trying to make a soccer division and get both the first and second place of the teams after playing their respective matches, I need to do this by comparing their total wins and in case of tie, by difference of total goals.

This is the class for the team:

```
class Equipo:
pais = None
media_gol = 0
penal = 0
nextGol = 0
puntos_divisionales = 0
dif_goles = 0

def __init__(self, pais, mg, pen):
    self.pais = pais
    self.media_gol = mg
    self.penal = pen

def getPais(self):
    return self.pais
def getMedia(self):
    return self.media_gol
def getPenal(self):
    return self.penal
def getGol(self):
    return self.nextGol
def getPuntos(self):
    return self.puntos_divisionales
def getDif(self):
    return self.dif_goles

def setNextGol(self, gol):
    self.nextGol += gol
def setGol(self, gol):
    self.nextGol = gol
def setDif(self, dif):
    self.dif_goles = dif

def incPuntos(self):
    self.puntos_divisionales += 1
```

And this is the Division class:

```
class Division:
primerLugar = None
segundoLugar = None
equipo1 = None
equipo2 = None
equipo3 = None
equipo4 = None
equipos = [equipo1, equipo2, equipo3, equipo4]
matches = []

def __init__(self, e1, e2, e3, e4):
    self.equipo1 = e1
    self.equipo2 = e2
    self.equipo3 = e3
    self.equipo4 = e4

def get1(self):
    return self.primerLugar

def get2(self):
    return self.segundoLugar

def match(self):
    self.matches.append([self.equipo1, self.equipo2])
    self.matches.append([self.equipo1, self.equipo3])
    self.matches.append([self.equipo1, self.equipo4])
    self.matches.append([self.equipo2, self.equipo3])
    self.matches.append([self.equipo2, self.equipo4])
    self.matches.append([self.equipo3, self.equipo4])

def winner(self):
    for m in self.matches:
        p = Partido(m[0], m[1])
        p.tiempoPartido()
        p.scoreGoles()
        p.getGanador().incPuntos()
```

Class "Partido" is just the game between both teams and the calculator for goals and winner.

I need to decide the winner in the Division Class

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of issues going on with your code. The equipo class seems good, although my spanish isn't good enough to figure out what most of the fields and functions do.

For the Division class, I would recommend creating a dictionary with the teams as keys and their division points and total goals as a list for items. Once all the games are played you would convert it to a list, then sort it. You can also get rid of your matches field and just user itertools.combinations. It makes every unique combination of 2 teams. The class would look something like this:

```
class Division:

  equipos = {equipo1: [0,0], equipo2: [0,0], equipo3: [0,0], equipo4: [0,0]}

  def __init__(self, e1, e2, e3, e4):
      self.equipo1 = e1
      self.equipo2 = e2
      self.equipo3 = e3
      self.equipo4 = e4

  def get1(self):
      return self.places[0]

  def get2(self):
      return self.places[1]

  def winner(self):
       #itertools.combinations(self.equipos.keys(), 2) basically makes a list of every unique pair of equipos.
       for m in itertools.combinations(self.equipos.keys(), 2):
            p = Partido(m[0], m[1])
            p.tiempoPartido()
            p.scoreGoles()
       #increase the winners score by 1
       equipos[p.getGanador()][0]+=1
       #increase the winners goal count by goals scored
       equipos[p.getGanador()][1]+=p.getGoals(0)
       #increase the losers goal count by goals scored
       equipos[p.getVencido()][1]+=p.getGoals(1)
       self.places = equipos.items()
       #sorts by division points
       self.places.sort(key = lambda x: -x[0][0])
       #sorts by goals scored
       self.places.sort(key = lambda x: -x[0][1])
```

You would need to implement a getGoals function in Partido to get the number of goals. I assumed you would do getGoals(0) for the winner's number of goals and getGoals(1) for loser's number of goals. You also need a getVencido (I think that is loser in Spanish?) function to return the losing team.